# How to update a different google sheet when pulling information from the first sheet?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I'm able to pull from googlesheets and update the same sheet I pulled from. (The script will only work for the first sheet for the google spreadsheet.)

After pulling from the first sheet I want to generate a report which works, but I don't want it to overwrite the first sheet, instead I want it to put the information on a separate sheet I made. Here's what I have sofar when trying to change my script to work with a different sheet.

```
def get_google_sheet(spreadsheet_id, range_name):
    # Retrieve sheet data using OAuth credentials and Google Python API.

    global scopes
    global gsheet

    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
    # Setup the Sheets API
    store = file.Storage('credentials1.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', scopes)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    # Call the Sheets API
    gsheet = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name).execute()

    return gsheet
```

```
def gsheet2df(gsheet):
    # Converts Google sheet data to a Pandas DataFrame.

    header = gsheet.get('values', [])[0]   # Assumes first line is header!
    values = gsheet.get('values', [])[1:]  # Everything else is data.
    #header = values[0]
    if not values:
        print('No data found.')
    else:
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(values)
        df.columns = header

        return df
```

```
def Export_Data_To_Sheets():


    store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', scopes)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    RANGE_AND_SHEET = "ReportListA1:E500"
    response_date = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
        spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
        valueInputOption='RAW',
        range=RANGE_AND_SHEET,
        body=dict(
            majorDimension='ROWS',
            values=df.T.reset_index().T.values.tolist())
    ).execute()
    print('Sheet successfully Updated')
```

When I use just the range without identifying the sheet it works no problem. With the range and sheet I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adaniel/PycharmProjects/EmailAutomation/venv/AutoEmailScript/test.py", line 126, in <module>
    Export_Data_To_Sheets()
  File "/Users/adaniel/PycharmProjects/EmailAutomation/venv/AutoEmailScript/test.py", line 68, in Export_Data_To_Sheets
    response_date = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
  File "/Users/adaniels/PycharmProjects/EmailAutomation/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/adaniels/PycharmProjects/EmailAutomation/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 840, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/*******yAABhNJvARr9BzsVLvCYSfpcvQAmpWESL-DJI/values/%28%27ReportList%21%27%2C%20%27A1%3AE500%27%29?valueInputOption=RAW&alt=json returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.
House", "10/19/19", NaN, NaN, NaN], ["Co
                    ^">
I already have two different credential files for different authentication scopes. I also deleted them and reauthenticated, so I'm not sure why I'm getting a 400 error.
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the line `sheet = service.open('ReportList').sheet`?

Comment: I was trying to have it access a specific sheet called 'ReportList', otherwise it will just update the first sheet.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You need to specify the sheet you wish to update in the `range` portion of the request.*

#### More Information:

`service.open('SheetName').sheet` is not a thing - `open` is not a method of the service, the Sheets service doesn't know at this point what Spreadsheet you are trying to update the values of.

As per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update), you need to specify the range of values you wish to update in the range parameter. This includes the Sheet name.

#### Code Snippet:

```
RANGE_AND_SHEET = "ReportList!" + RANGE_NAME
response_date = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
        spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, 
        range=RANGE_AND_SHEET, 
        valueInputOption='RAW',
        body=value_range_body).execute()
```

#### References:

- [Method: `spreadsheets.values.update` | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)